# Count consecutive days off - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE resource_calendar_attendance
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character(256),
    hour_from double precision,
    hour_to double precision,
    calendar_id integer,
    day_period character(256)
);
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(1, 'Monday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(2, 'Monday Evening', 8, 13, 17, 'afternoon');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(3, 'Tuesday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(4, 'Tuesday Evening', 8, 13, 17, 'afternoon');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(5, 'Wednesday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(6, 'Wednesday Evening', 8, 13, 17, 'afternoon');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(7, 'Thursday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(8, 'Thursday Evening', 8, 13, 17, 'afternoon');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(9, 'Friday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(10, 'Friday Evening', 8, 13, 17, 'afternoon');
INSERT INTO resource_calendar_attendance(id, name, hour_from, hour_to, calendar_id, day_period) VALUES(11, 'Saturday Morning', 8, 12, 1, 'morning');
 
CREATE TABLE resource_calendar
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character(256)
);
INSERT INTO resource_calendar(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Standard 40 Hours/Week');

CREATE TABLE hr_attendance
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    calendar_id integer NOT NULL,
    employee_name character(256),
    check_in timestamp,
    check_out timestamp
);

INSERT INTO hr_attendance(id, calendar_id, employee_name, check_in, check_out) VALUES(1, 1, 'Jame', '2020-09-01 07:00:00', '2020-09-01 18:00:00');
INSERT INTO hr_attendance(id, calendar_id, employee_name, check_in, check_out) VALUES(2, 1, 'Alex', '2020-09-01 07:30:00', '2020-09-01 17:45:00');
INSERT INTO hr_attendance(id, calendar_id, employee_name, check_in, check_out) VALUES(3, 1, 'Jame', '2020-09-07 07:12:00', '2020-09-07 18:22:00');
INSERT INTO hr_attendance(id, calendar_id, employee_name, check_in, check_out) VALUES(4, 1, 'Alex', '2020-09-02 07:07:00', '2020-09-02 18:08:00');
INSERT INTO hr_attendance(id, calendar_id, employee_name, check_in, check_out) VALUES(5, 1, 'Alex', '2020-09-03 06:13:00', '2020-09-03 18:24:00');
```

1. How to count 5 consecutive days off?

```
Jame: 2020-09-01 --> Check in OK
2020-09-02 --> No Check in
2020-09-03 --> NO check in
2020-09-04 --> NO check in 
2020-09-05  --> NO check in
2020-09-06 --> week end
2020-09-07  --> NO check in
2020-09-08 --> Check in OK
```

==> Name = Jame (Count days off >= 5 days)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/95dbc

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Add a sample result of what you want. I dont understand what you mean by `count 5 consecutive days off`. Which table are u even querying?

Comment: What is the purpose of tables `resource_calendar_attendance` and `resource_calendar`, and how are we supposed to use them in the query?

Comment: 'resource_calendar_attendance' table tells us which day is the weekend. 2020-09-01 and 2020-09-08, Jame checked in. From 2020-09-02 to 2020-09-07  he checked in --> he had 6 days off. But we look 'resource_calendar_attendance' table, sunday is the weekend, so Jame had 5 days off @leoOrion and #GMB. So i want to add 'WHERE' condition 'COUNT(days) >=5'. Thanks